# ConTeXt: Height fitting with row spanning in a table

Tags: tables, context, height, fit

How can I shrink the `height` of the foo cell to fit its content?

```
\starttext

\startTABLE
    \NC foo \NC[nr=2]\input knuth   \NC \NR
    \NC bar \NC                         \NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a not perfect solution: setting manually the `height` of the bar cell shrinks the foo cell (setting `height=fit` for the foo cell does **not** work).

```
\starttext

\startTABLE
    \NC foo                 \NC[nr=2] \input knuth  \NC \NR
    \NC[height=28ex] bar    \NC                         \NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

I have chosen `28ex` for the `height` because linespace in ConTeXt is equal to `2.8ex` and I need the height of 10 lines in this example to fit the knuth paragraph (if I could find a way to get automatically the number of lines required to fit the knuth paragraph it would be better).

[image]